# Highmaps, how to pass data from CSV to my world map

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I have a large CSV file from which I need to select data from various columns and put them on a highmaps map.

How can I select the columns to use for the map? Lets say that I have country names at column 0, country codes at column 8 and number of things at column 1. How can I pass them to the map.

This is the CSV reader I use:

```
            $.get('downloads/dg_mare_piwik_countries.csv', function(data) {
            // Split the lines

    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');
        if(lineNo !== 0) {
            var iso_country = items[9],
            name=items[0],
            no_items = parseFloat(items[1]);
            //options.series[0].data.push([visits]);
            options.series[0].data.push({
            name: name,
            code3: iso_country,
            value: no_items
        });
            }

        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Map(options);
    });
```

And the Map, copied from the highmaps example

```
            var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart_container'
            },
        title: {
            text: 'Fixed tooltip with HTML'
        },

        legend: {
            title: {
                text: 'Population density per km²',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            useHTML: true,
            padding: 0,
            pointFormat: '<span class="f32"><span class="flag {point.flag}"></span></span>' +
                ' {point.name}: <b>{point.value}</b>/km²',
            positioner: function () {
                return { x: 0, y: 250 };
            }
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 1,
            max: 1000,
            type: 'logarithmic'
        },

        series: [{
            data: [],
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
            joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
            name: 'Population density',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            }
        }]
    };
```

Sorry for being perhaps too ignorant. I cannot short it out and any help will be deeply appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the Highcharts data module to load csv? http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module

Comment: Indeed, it has worked perfectly with that. Thank you so much!